# Program isn't showing up

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project3x4 {
public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    double totalRegularHours;
    double overTimeHours;
    overTimeHours = reader.nextDouble();

    double hourlyWage;
    hourlyWage = reader.nextDouble();

    double overTimePay;
    overTimePay = overTimeHours * (1.5 * hourlyWage);

    double totalWeeklyPay;


    System.out.print("Enter the Hourly Wage: ");
    hourlyWage = reader.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the total amount of regular hours: ");
    totalRegularHours = reader.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the total amount of over time hours: ");
    overTimeHours = reader.nextDouble();

    totalWeeklyPay = totalRegularHours * hourlyWage + overTimePay;

    System.out.print("The Total weekly pay is $" );
    System.out.println(totalWeeklyPay);
    }
```

}

For some reason the program just won't run(display) on eclipse. I also tried to run it on CMD, same result. No error is mentioned.

I couldn't quite figure out what's wrong with it can someone please help?

Comment: How did you try to run it?

Comment: How are you running it in Eclipse? How are you running it on the command line? What do you see when you try to run it?

Comment: It runs fine. Your code is just waiting for two double values before printing anything.

Comment: I tried. It works, just type something in the console.

Comment: When I run (run button) it on eclipse the console remains blank, nothing is showing. I tried it with other programs they all worked perfectly except this one.

Comment: Try removing lines containing `reader.nextDouble();` located before first `System.out.print`.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. It seems that i have to enter 2 any random number before the console to display. Can someone explain this?

Comment: By invoking `overTimeHours = reader.nextDouble();` your code is waiting until user will provide some value in console. Since you are invoking `reader.nextDouble();` twice before any printing statement you need to write two double numbers before you will see any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you. Declare your variables first and don't read from scanner until you have prompted the user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project3x4 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        double totalRegularHours;
        double overTimeHours;
        double hourlyWage;
        double totalWeeklyPay;


        System.out.print("Enter the Hourly Wage: ");
        hourlyWage = reader.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the total amount of regular hours: ");
        totalRegularHours = reader.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the total amount of over time hours: ");
        overTimeHours = reader.nextDouble();

        double overTimePay;
        overTimePay = overTimeHours * (1.5 * hourlyWage);

        totalWeeklyPay = totalRegularHours * hourlyWage + overTimePay;

        System.out.print("The Total weekly pay is $" );
        System.out.println(totalWeeklyPay);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 Declaring values before they are needed like this is not necessary and awful style.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'll try it immediately when I have the chance. I appreciate your help

Comment: @raptortech97 I don't understand what you mean by your comment. "Declaring values before they are needed" being not necessary? Where would you put them - randomly throughout your code? If the code has many lines and the variable gets used many times, what does it matter where the declaration occurs. -1 for you.

Comment: Variables should be declared where they are first used. They should not be declared in a block at the start of the function. This is standard Java style.

Comment: @raptortech97 where are you getting this 'standard Java style' reference from by the way? Also, I mainly just copied the op's code from above and modified it to get it working - so it shouldn't be a -1 to me...

Comment: Come over to [CodeReview.se] with a sample like this to learn common practices and idioms

Comment: Ok @raptortech97, but I actually wanted you to do your homework and give me a proper answer. I think the answer is: it depends on which style guide you use. For example Google's Java Style Guide, see this link to [Variable Declarations](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.8.2-variable-declarations). Note section *4.8.2.2* describes what you told me above.